# Record keeping of sealed radioactive sources

Tags: logs, inventory, signature

I am wondering if someone knows of an open-source software that helps you keep track of the use (lease/return) of sealed radioactive sources in a physics laboratory. It would need functions such as:

- overview of current leases: person A has leased source X for his experiment in location B until day Y
- inventory of available sources: sources A, B, C are still available with an activity of D E F
- digital signature by responsible of facility allowing the lease, and digital signature by user confirming the return
- A log of what has happened to each source: leased day A, return day B by user M, again out day C, back day D by user N, etc.
- Optionally printing out number of hours used by each user for a given source

So it is mixture of a library lease management software, an inventory management software, and digital signatures with e-certificates.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: CERN has something https://geso.web.cern.ch but it looks closed-source